# Why doesn't the TextArea allow me to expand it wider

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Basically as you can see in the code I tried to set it to 1000px wide just to show its not changing the size at all it wont go any bigger I can make it smaller but not wider.  I added some spacing so you can see what I am talking about easier.

The Snippet asked for

```html
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.businessJustification, new { id = "businessJustification", name = "businessJustification", @cols = 40, @rows = 3,@style="width: 1000px;"}) </p>
```

Original Code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Software Request";
}
@model project1.Model.TicketModel

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
</head>


<body style="background-color:#D1D3D4;"></body>
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#D1D3D4;">
    <img src="/Images/TECH_BARlogoBLACK.png" style="width:1000px;height:200px;" class="animate__heartBeat">
    <p class="lead" span style="background-color: #FFFF00;">Software Request</p>
    <br>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
        {
    <p class="text-left"><b>Enter Computer Name:</b></p>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.computerName, new { id = "computerName", name = "computerName"}) 
     <p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><b>To obtain your Computer Name: </b>Click Start (bottom left windows icon) and type in System Information, On the 5th line, your Computer Name is listed as the System Name <br></p>
    <p class="text-left" style="width: 1000px;"><b>Business Justification:</b> <br> 


    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.businessJustification, new { id = "businessJustification", name = "businessJustification", @cols = 40, @rows = 3,@style="width: 1000px;"}) </p>



    <label for="Software">Select the Software(s) you need!</label>
    <br>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => @Model.selectedSoftwareList, new MultiSelectList(Model.softwareList, "Text", @Model.selectedSoftwareList),
                                                    new
                                                    {
                                                        id = "_SelectedSoftwareList",
                                                        @class = "form-control multiselect-dropdown",
                                                        multiple = "true",
                                                        style = "width:200px;height:300px;",
                                                        data_placeholder = "Select Software"
                                                    })
    <br>
    <br><button type="submit" class="btn-primary btn-lg" style="font-size: 20px">Submit</button>
        }

</div>


<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
.buttonBig {
    display: block;
    width: 10%;
    border: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

I have provided a image of how small the "1000px" wide box is and if I set this to like 200px it is also the same size.
[image]

Comment: Please create a [mre] with the rendered HTML and CSS. Preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar).

Comment: That's the opposite of what was asked for. The **rendered** HTML would be something like `<textarea id="businessJustification" name="businessJustification" cols=40 rows=3 style="width: 1000px;"></textarea>` and I expect there is HTML and CSS around that that is likely causing the problem, because if you put the HTML of just that `textarea` in a Stack Snippet, you'll find that it is 1000 pixels wide.

Comment: I click the snippet tool and paste in the code like it asks.

Comment: I edited your question, clicked the snippet tool, and pasted the ASP.NET Razor code provided into the HTML box. As expected, when clicking on the "Run code snippet" box, it does not show a textarea because that requires an ASP.NET server. What I'm saying is, go to the browser, that you have made a screenshot of, right click on the textarea and select Inspect. then right-click on the element and select Copy > Copy outerHTML. That may be different based on your browser maker. We also need the styles that apply to that HTML.